# On input:focus icon color change not working

Tags: css, less, pug

I want to change the color of icon on input:focus. I've tried it with "+" method. but not working for me. Code is in Jade and LESS. Used font-awesome for icon.

**JADE**

```
header
  .search
    input(type="text", placeholder="seach")
    i.fa.fa-search
```

**LESS**

```
.search input:focus +  .search i{color: @link-color !important;}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.search` is not a sibling of the input, it is the parent. You need to just have the icon as the sibling.

```
.search input:focus + i{color: @link-color !important;}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/Bvfog)